# Keystroke in AppleScript maps numbers to those on keypad, which cause some problems

Tags: applescript, keycode

I need to send some keys to another program, and I tried `keystroke` in AppleScript. Everything worked well until I found that when I sent numbers to a Windows program running in Parallels virtual machine, it didn't work, but instead, it change the position of cursor.

Then I use program keyboardSee to find what's wrong, and I found that all numbers and some symbols are mapped to the keys on numeric keypad, not the numeric line. So maybe the NumLock is off in the virtual machine, and the keys mapped to keypad trigger not numeric but control keys.

I found some people says that use `key code` can solve this problem, but I cannot find a perfect char-to-keycode table, and I also notice that people said key code could be different for the same character in different keyboard layout.

So how can I solve this problem perfectly, means how can I make it always map numbers to numeric line, and perform the same in no matter what keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to say that I don't think this is possible at the moment. In general, Mac apps know that macs don't even have the same characters on their Numberpads that PCs do (no arrows, no num lock, etc), so the distinction is meaningless. Some poorly ported Mac apps do make a distinction though, such as World of Warcraft (although it isn't the worst port out there by any means). I believe parallels has a num lock in its menus somewhere (if I recall correctly), so you should be able to get around it that way.